# Xcode libtool error -- "foo.o is an object file (not allowed in a library)"

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, linker-errors, libtool-xcode

I am seeing a lot of this error when I try to link my current project.  What am I to make of it?

Here is the hopefully relevant portion of the log.  I have redacted part of some of the paths:

```
Libtool "[path]/Build/Intermediates/extobjc.build/Release-iOS-Internal-iphoneos/libextobjc (iOS).build/Objects-normal/armv6/libextobjc_iOS.a" normal armv6
cd [path]/libextobjc
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.0
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only armv6 -syslibroot /[Path]/Build/Products/Release-iOS-Internal-iphoneos -filelist "[path]/extobjc.build/Release-iOS-Internal-iphoneos/libextobjc (iOS).build/Objects-normal/armv6/extobjc_iOS.LinkFileList" -framework Foundation -o "[path]/extobjc.build/Release-iOS-Internal-iphoneos/libextobjc (iOS).build/Objects-normal/armv6/libextobjc_iOS.a"

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/libtool: file: [path]/Build/Intermediates/extobjc.build/Release-iOS-Internal-iphoneos/libextobjc (iOS).build/Objects-normal/armv6/EXTMultiObject.o is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
```

EDIT: hopefully it is clear from the log -- but the trouble comes when linking a library.

Comment: In Terminal what does: file (iOS).build/Objects-normal/armv6/EXTMultiObject.o  tell you?

Answer (score 3):

I got a similar error. It seems like xCode is ignoring all ".a" files when commiting/checking-out from a SVN repository. I put these files manually and did a clean build.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I changed my macbook and that was exactly the problem.